# Script to change the line #include at all my .c files

Tags: python, bash, zsh

I am trying to recompose a project with many files and I need to change the #include of all of them, does anyone have any recommendations?

example of what I need:

```
#include "lib.h"
```

has to be changed to

```
#include "../inc/lib.h"
```

Comment: This is a simple `sed` command. You can also probably do it with a global replace in your IDE.

Comment: This can be done using `sed` as @Barmar suggested. Try to implement it yourself and If you run into any issues, or get any errors, you can come back and ask for help.

Comment: I'd adjust the compiler options to use an appropriate `-I dir` instead of editing the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

```
gcc <options> <newName> -I <path to lib.h>
```

or, a bit more complicated, something using grep and sed